# Is there a way to scan a csv file with varied row lengths into a list?

Tags: r, csv, import, read.table

I have a csv file with a few million lines. Each line can have lengths between 5 and 10. I can use `read.table()` to read in the data by padding out each row to length 10 with NAs or empty strings, however, removing these NAs later is time consuming. I would like to read the file into a list of vectors, so that each line can have it's own list element, negating the need for padding the rows with NAs or empty strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `readLines()` with `strsplit()`:

```
test <- strsplit(readLines("MyFile.csv"),",")
```